# Consulta não retorna valor

Tags: php, query

Eu tenho uma consulta no header da página que retorna o title, o meta name="description" e o meta name="keywords" que funciona muito bem. Porém, ao aplicar esta mesma estrutura de consulta no corpo da página não retorna valor algum. Já testei a query no PHPMyAdmin e está correta. Mas na página não funciona.

```
$limi = 1;
$tit = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT id_orclinha, dc, orclinha
FROM pe_orclinhas
WHERE id_orclinha = 458 
LIMIT 0 , ?");
$tit->execute(array($limi));
$dados = $tit->fetch();
$cabeca = $dados['orclinha'];   

echo $cabeca;
```

Comment: Provavelmente ele está escapando para `LIMIT 0, "1"`, tornando inválido.

Comment: Era isso mesmo irmão. Obrigado